# How can I programmatically insert date field values?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, datetime

I have a bunch of values from a .sql export that are in the datetime format (same format that date fields take in the DB). I'm creating nodes using these date values. How can I insert these values into the date field?

I tried:

```
$node->field_data_field_date['und'][0]['field_date_value'] = $datetime_value;
```

but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your field's name is `field_date` you should access it by using

```
$node->field_date['und'][0]['value'] = $datetime_value;
```

And if it has an "end" date you have to set its `value2` property.

Try to install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), create a node for the content type you want to use and go to the devel tab `node/123/devel` to explore its object.

Comment: D'oh! Guess I got thrown off by the two values and didn't realize that it operates the same as every other field. Thanks for the answer!